# regexunicode - Accented characters are removed when using preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, unicode, utf-8, preg-match-all

I have the the problem described in title.
If I use

```
preg_match_all('/\pL+/u', $_POST['word'], $new_word);
```

and I type *hello à and ì* the new_word returned is *hello and  *
Why?

Someone advised me to specify all characters I want to convert in this way

```
preg_match_all('/\pL+/u', $_POST['word'], 'aäeëioöuáéíóú');
```

, but I want my application works with all existing accents (for a multilanguage website).
Can you help me?
Thanks.

**EDIT:** I specify that I utilise this regex to purify punctuation. It well purify all punctuation but unicode characters are wrong returned, in fact are not even returned.

**EDIT 2:** I am sorry, but I very badly explained.
The problem is not in preg_match_all but in

```
str_word_count($my_key, 2, 'aäáàeëéèiíìoöóòuúù');
```

I had to manually specify accented characters but I think there are many others. Right?

Answer (score 3):

`\pL` should match all utf8 characters and spaces. Be sure, that `$_POST['word']` is a string encoded with utf8. If not, try `utf8_encode()` before matching or check the encoding of your HTML form. In my tests, your example works like a charm.

You may use this together with `count()` to get the number of words. Then you need not care about the possible characters. `\pL` will do this for you. This should do the trick:

```
$string = "áll thât words wíth ìntérnâtiønal çhårs";

preg_match_all('/\pL+/u', $string, $words);
echo count($words[0]); // returns: 6
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer.
The problem is I wish to realise an application compatible with many languages (such as european, arabic, chinese, cyrillic, etc).
In this way I cannot obtain a general solution but limited to the specified characters in the 3rd regex parameter

Comment: What exactly do you want to match? If you want to match a string that may contain some of these (international) characters, it should be possible with your first example. In my tests, the complete result of the matching can be found in `$new_word` (_hello à and ì_). Or do you just want to count the words (even if they contain such characters)?

Comment: Hi,
the problem is in str_word_count instruction!
If I do not specify all special characters, the caracters not specified are not showed!
For this reason I specified some accented characters, but I think there are many other characters to include, because my intention is to offer a multilanguage service.

Comment: I edited my answer above and added a `count` to get the number of words using your regex. This should help you to count the words of strings without specifying all the possible multilanguage characters.

Comment: count function process an array.
My key is not an array, but a phrase token from $_POST['key']. For this reason I utilise str_word_count which takes a phrase and return an array with a word for each index.

Comment: `count` is used one `$words` which is the result of `preg_match_all`. `preg_match_all` returns an array containing all your words.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mb_ereg_match()` (instead of `preg_match()`) from [Multibyte String](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) PHP library. It is specially made for working with multibyte strings.